# Need to be able to pass many variables in PHP 8.x

Tags: php, max

I have a website running on GoDaddy, dedicated server, and I recently updated to version 9 of Linux. Also upgraded to version 8.x of php. I have forms that have a lot of data to pass around to the various routines and this used to work perfectly under php version 5.4. After the upgrade, when I run the program that updates the database, only about 100 variables get passed using the `<form> .... </form>` with a submit line to the update routine. This used to work just fine under 5.4 but not any more!
I've updated the php.ini files (local as well as system) to increase the number of variables but to no effect.
I can see that most of the variables are passed when I do a `var_dump($_REQUEST)` but after about 100 entries, there aren't anymore.

Tried setting `post_max_size` to 0, also to 12M in the php.ini files. 0 is supposed to be unlimited, but still not working.
What else could it be?

Comment: What is the value of `max_input_vars`? The default is 1,000.

Comment: I set it to zero, before it was set to 8M.

Comment: max_input_vars is set to 4000

Comment: Did you restart the server after changing php.ini?

Comment: `max_input_vars` is a per-directory setting, check the `.htaccess` file in the directory. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php

Comment: max_input_vars is set to 4000 in all php.ini files (directory, home and WHM). Yes, I rebooted the server, still not working.

Comment: If you do `echo ini_get('max_input_vars');`  what does it show?

Comment: <?php
  echo ini_get('max_input_vars');

?>

Comment: The above program prints out 4000

Comment: Is the form using `GET` or `POST`?

Comment: I changed it in the php.ini files to 12000, now the test script says 12000, so the php.ini files are being read. However, the other program still won't post more than about 100 variables

Comment: Are you getting an exception that you are exceeding max_input_vars?

Comment: The program is using POST. <form method=\"post\" action=......>

Comment: Am not getting any errors saying I've exceeded anything. Just when I do the Var_dump, the output only gives about 100 variables.

Comment: It has been a while, but I thought there was either a warning or an exception when that happens. I’m just checking that you are chasing the right problem

Comment: If you view the request in the Network tab on the client, do you see all the parameters being sent? Do they all have different names?

Comment: I created a test program to pass a list of variables and do a dump. All of the variables were passed to the routine called and I didn't get any missing elements until I reached the limit set by php.ini.

Comment: Looking at the code, it seems that the missing data is related to checkboxes. I put the checkbox value into an array and I don't think it liked it because most of the data after that was missing. So not a php.ini failure, the parameters are working as advertized.

Comment: So the original question can be closed.